Upgraded github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3, SQLite Version Not Reflecting in SQLite Browser
I recently upgraded the github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 package in my Go project from version 1.14.16 to 1.14.20. Prior to the upgrade, the SQLite version reported by the sqlite_version() function was 3.39.2. However, after the upgrade, the reported SQLite version is 3.45.0 when queried within the Go code.
However, when I check the SQLite version using a SQLite browser, it still shows version 3.39.2.
What could be the reason behind this discrepancy? Am I missing something in the upgrade process or is there another step I need to take to ensure the SQLite browser reflects the updated version? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
attaching below snippet which is printing correct version. But in sqlite3 browser it is showing older.
 var version string
err = db.QueryRow("SELECT sqlite_version()").Scan(&version)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error querying database:", err)
    return
}

// Display version information
fmt.Println("SQLite version:", version)


Why not just take SQLite Browser's code and figure out how it obtains the SQLite's version? I'd start there.
